# How does browser decide when to request a cached file again?

Tags: php, html, performance, caching, server

I have a webpage that I am caching for 12 hours. These are two screenshots of the response headers.

[image]

and

[image]

As you can see both the 'Date' and 'Expires' header have changed in values. My understanding is that 'Date' is the time when file is requested by us and 'Expires' is the time when the browser is supposed to check for a newer version. After an interval of four minutes both the values have updated. So, how does browser decide when it is time to request newer version of file? Will it not cause the file to be cached indefinitely?

I understand that the 'Expires' value is just a suggestion for the browser. But how does browser know the time when the file was requested for first time because 'Date' header also gets updated each time.

I have one more question. My webpages have `.php` extension. However, my header shows:

```
Content Type : "text/html"
```

Why is this happening? `Content Type : "text/html"` causes my webpages to be cached. Caching does not happen on pages that have `session_start()`? Is it because of the `session_start()` or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: If you want pages not to be cached, you can send the appropriate `Cache-Control` header.

Answer (score 3):

1. HTTP 'Date' header is just the current date and time on the server. See the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for more details. It has no relation whatsoever to the resource (file/page) being served
2. HTTP 'Expires' header is an advice for browser, usually it's set in your web server config or directly in the application code. In most cases it's current time + some extra hours/days as seen reasonable by webmaster. So if expiration is set to, let's say, 3 days – 'Expires' will always show current time in 'Date' field and current time + 3 days in 'Expires' field. Doesn't really matter when the file was updated, it has no effect.

If your browser has this file in cache and the original 'Expires' moment hasn't arrived yet – browser will use the cached version. There are some ways to force update though.

3. If your PHP outputs HTML (which is true in many cases), content type of 'text/html' is totally correct. It could be 'application/json', 'image/png' and anything else when appropriate. PHP is the programming language, and content type refers to the format of data received from HTTP server, it could be just anything.

Comment: If the browser keeps setting 'Expires' field to current time + 3 days, won't it cause the file to be cached indefinitely. Am I missing something?

Comment: Of course it won't! After 3 days the browser will download a new copy, and if the file has been updated – browser will get an updated file. It's similar to TTL field in DNS – it means how much time it's okay to keep the file and not consider it outdated.

Comment: So, the values in 'Date' and 'Expires' field don't matter? The browser will always request a newer version  three days days after the first request?

Comment: Of course they do. Browser will request new version after the moment mentioned in 'Expires' arrives. So if 'Expires' says check again in 3 days - browser will check again in 3 days, unless you force refresh. And 'Date' is a reference timestamp

Comment: But they both get updated whenever I reload a webpage won't this result in indefinite caching?

Comment: You are right, both values will get updated on each an every request. But your browser stores the original expires date and will not fetch cached files as long as the expires date is not exceeded. This means the browser WILL NOT notice the update of the expires field ;-)

Comment: Yes, it won't notice it because it won't even fetch this path/resource.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part only.

Php pages dynamic create html pages you then send to the client. To the client it's just html.

Comment: So any `.htaccess` rules applied to `.html` will be applicable on `.php` files?

Comment: I don't belive that is the case. What they recived is html, but to the server who handles .htaccess it's not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The Date and Expires headers come from the server. If the resource served has an explicit date (for example, it is an actual file on disk, or it a script that sets a Date header), then the server will use that date. Otherwise, the server will use the current date.

If you upload a new file, the browser will not normally request the resource again from the server while the browser's cache of the file is still valid. If the user clears their cache, or forces a refresh, then the browser will query the server and receive the updated content.

Note that, cache expiry headers are advisory. The browser is free to re-request any resource any time it wants. (But for performance reasons, browsers usually cache anything and everything they can for as long as they can.)

By default, any page served by PHP will have `Content-type: text/html`. This is normal. PHP code can, of course, change this to anything else, and this is normally done any time PHP is serving non-html content.

Any page that uses sessions will usually not be cached. This is also normal. The reason for this is that generally, the page content is dependent on the session data (for example, the user currently logged in), and caching would be undesirable.

To your updated question: what's happening is, you're forcing the web page to reload (from the server). So when it does, the server is going to provide it updated information. When you tell the browser to reload (as opposed to just going to the page), you're explicitly telling it to ignore the cache and re-request the resource. That's why your Date and Expires headers appear to march forward.

Comment: Will the Date and Expires headers still come from server if the file is not cached?

Comment: @SanJeetSingh practically, the server will always send a date. (There are a very few cases in which it might not.) Whether the server sends an Expires header or not depends entirely on configuration.

Comment: Could you please also answer the second part where I mentioned that `.php` pages that don't have `session_start()` are cached while pages that don't have `session_start()` are not cached. Why does this happen?

Comment: If the browser keeps updating the date header and the file is meant to expires 12 hours after it was last requested. Will this cause the file to be cached indefinitely? Am I missing something?

Comment: Updated. Also, the *browser* does not set the Date header. The *server* provides both the Date and Expires headers. As long as both the server and client have their clocks set right, you're not going to accidentally get something cached indefinitely.

Comment: Does this mean the expires header has no effect on when a file is to be requested again?

Comment: The Expires header is *advisory*. The browser is free to take the advice, or ignore it. Usually it will do what has been requested.

Comment: I have rephrased my question above to be more clear about what I am asking. Could you please take a look at it. I think I did not explain it correctly the first time.